# prove that $2^{35}-1$ is divisible by 31 and 127

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can you give me a hint to how to approach the problem.How one can show that $2^{35}-1$ is a multiple of 31 and 127?

Comment: $31=2^5-1, 127=2^7-1$

Comment: What do you even think about the problem? Where are your thoughts?

Comment: The result of the division is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186539/prove-that-2pq-1-2p-1-sumq-1-i-0-2pi-for-two-natural-num)

Comment: prove you've attempted the problem and actually have a brain ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$2^7\equiv1 \mod 127$ and $2^5\equiv1 \mod 31$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can use that $$2^5\equiv 1 \mod 31$$
and $$2^{35}-1\equiv 0 \mod 127$$

Comment: So $16\equiv 1\pmod{31}$?

Comment: Did you mean $2^\color{red}5\equiv1\mod31$?

Comment: Yes, thats what i meant.